# Any way to get json of the facebook page in 2019?

Tags: json, facebook, parsing, facebook-javascript-sdk, squarespace

I'm trying to make parser from facebook page posts to Squarespace blog posts. I already did it for Instagram but I need json file of the Facebook page.
I need something similar as I have for inst (https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[USER-ID]/media/recent?access_token=[TOKEN]);

I found few articles how to do it but all of them was made before the facebook’s massive data leak and after that they have made many changes to their app’s permissions and imposed many other rules.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/

- You need a Page Token of the Page if you own the Page
- You need [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) approved by Facebook for Pages you do not own

Since you tagged the question with the JS SDK: Make sure not to use hardcoded Access Token on the client! They are always meant to be kept secret.